# Remove last numbers in rows in R

Tags: r

This is a fragment of my data.frame:

```
MC0_1_N.1   a   c
MC0_1_N.2   d   b
MC0_5_N.1   b   c
MC0_5_N.2   c   d
MC0_5_N.3   a   b
MC0_5_N.4   e   f
MC0_5_N.5   a   h
MC0_5_N.6   k   m
MC0_5_N.7   s   z
MC0_5_N.8   o   p
MC0_5_N.9   p   r
MC0_5_N.10  r   t
```

Is there any way to remove the last numbers of rows (1,2,3,4...) which formed after creating data.frame?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given example this would work quite fine:

```
df1$col1 <- strtrim(df1$col1,7)
```

Of course this only works when

- column variables are strings
- there are no items like `MC0_10_N.1` in the dataframe (mind the two digit `10` in the middle)

Note, this also removes the `.` before the number.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to match the dot (`\\.` -escape as it is a metacharacter meaning any character) followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace by blank (`""`)

```
df1$col1 <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", df1$col1)
df1$col1
#[1] "MC0_1_N" "MC0_1_N" "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N"
#[8] "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N" "MC0_5_N"
```

NOTE: Here we assumed it is the first column.  If it is `row.names` then replace `df1$col1` with `row.names(df1)`

i.e.

```
row.names(df1) <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", row.names(df1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `df` and `col1` your dataframe and name of the column you wish to alter:

```
unlist(lapply(stringi::stri_split(str = df$col1,regex = "\\."),function(x) x[[1]]))
```

resulting in:

```
MC0_1_N
MC0_1_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
MC0_5_N
```